# Eliminar Fila de tabla Javascript

Tags: javascript

Hola buenas tengo una tabla, y en cada fila tengo un logo y me gustaría que al hacer accionarlo , me eliminase esa fila en concreto...mi codigo es este,os dejo la funcion eliminar aunque este mal...Gracias

```js
<script>
    function createContact(){
            var mitabla = document.getElementById("tableContact");
            var elementos = mitabla.rows.length;
            var row =mitabla.insertRow(elementos);
            var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
            var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
            var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
            var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
            var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
            var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
            var cell7 = row.insertCell(6);
            
            cell1.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="fname" size="12">';
            cell2.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="fname" size="12">';
            cell3.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="fname" size="12">';
            cell4.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="fname" size="12">';
            cell5.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="fname" size="12">'; 
            cell6.innerHTML = '<input type="checkbox" name="email" value="1">';
            cell7.innerHTML = '<img onclick=modificarContacto(); src="../graphics/edita1.jpg" height="20" width="20"><img onclick=eliminarContacto(this);  src="../graphics/delete12.jpg" height="20" width="20">';

                            }
                            
function eliminarContacto(id){
        var row = document.getElementById("");

         document.getElementById("tableContact").deleteRow(row);
        
    }
    
</script>
```

```html
<body id='bdcuerpo'  name='bdcuerpo'>
    <div class="campoNuevoContact" >
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>
             <button onclick="createContact()">Nuevo contacto</button> 
             </th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
<div class="content1">
    <div>
        <table class="contactTable" name="tableContact" id="tableContact">
              <tr>
                 <th class="tableth">Nombre</th>
                 <th class="tableth">Apellidos</th>
                 <th class="tableth">Telefono</th>
                 <th class="tableth">Email</th>
                 <th class="tableth">Cargo</th>
                 <th class="tableth">Permitir emails</th>
                 <th class="tableth">Acciones</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  
                 <th class="filo">1111111</th>
                 <th class="filo">111111</th>
                 <th class="filo">11111</th>
                 <th class="filo">11111</th>
                 <th class="filo">111111</th>
                 <th class="filo"><input type="checkbox" name="email" value="1"></th>
                 <th class="filo">
                    <img onclick=modificarContacto(); onmouseover="this.style.cursor='hand'" onmouseout="this.style.cursor='default'" src="../graphics/edita1.jpg" height="20" width="20">
                    <img onclick=eliminarContacto(this); onmouseover="this.style.cursor='hand'" onmouseout="this.style.cursor='default'" src="../graphics/delete12.jpg" height="20" width="20">

                 </th>
              </tr>
```

```js
   function eliminarContacto(id){
        var row = document.getElementById("");

         document.getElementById("tableContact").deleteRow(row);
        
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El elemento que pasas a la función es el de la imagen pulsada. Para recuperar el elemento de celda o de fila debes recorrer los elementos padre.

Por otro lado al método `deleteRow` debes pasarle el índice de fila que puedes obtenerlo a partir de la propiedad `rowIndex`:

```js
function createContact(){
      var mitabla = document.getElementById("tableContact");
      var elementos = mitabla.rows.length;
      var row =mitabla.insertRow(elementos);
      var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
      var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
      var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
      var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
      var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
      var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
      var cell7 = row.insertCell(6);

      cell1.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="fname" size="12">';
      cell2.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="fname" size="12">';
      cell3.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="fname" size="12">';
      cell4.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="fname" size="12">';
      cell5.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="fname" size="12">'; 
      cell6.innerHTML = '<input type="checkbox" name="email" value="1">';
      cell7.innerHTML = '<img onclick=modificarContacto(); src="../graphics/edita1.jpg" height="20" width="20"><img onclick=eliminarContacto(this);  src="../graphics/delete12.jpg" height="20" width="20">';
}
                            
function eliminarContacto(id){
  // cell element
  var cell = id.parentNode;
  // row element
  var row = cell.parentNode;

  document.getElementById("tableContact").deleteRow(row.rowIndex);
}
```

```html
<body id='bdcuerpo'  name='bdcuerpo'>
    <div class="campoNuevoContact" >
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>
             <button onclick="createContact()">Nuevo contacto</button> 
             </th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
<div class="content1">
    <div>
        <table class="contactTable" name="tableContact" id="tableContact">
              <tr>
                 <th class="tableth">Nombre</th>
                 <th class="tableth">Apellidos</th>
                 <th class="tableth">Telefono</th>
                 <th class="tableth">Email</th>
                 <th class="tableth">Cargo</th>
                 <th class="tableth">Permitir emails</th>
                 <th class="tableth">Acciones</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  
                 <th class="filo">1111111</th>
                 <th class="filo">111111</th>
                 <th class="filo">11111</th>
                 <th class="filo">11111</th>
                 <th class="filo">111111</th>
                 <th class="filo"><input type="checkbox" name="email" value="1"></th>
                 <th class="filo">
                    <img onclick=modificarContacto(); onmouseover="this.style.cursor='hand'" onmouseout="this.style.cursor='default'" src="../graphics/edita1.jpg" height="20" width="20">
                    <img onclick=eliminarContacto(this); onmouseover="this.style.cursor='hand'" onmouseout="this.style.cursor='default'" src="../graphics/delete12.jpg" height="20" width="20">

                 </th>
              </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes de conocer el índice para eliminar la fila.

```
function eliminarContacto(img){
    var rowIndex = img.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
    document.getElementById("tableContact").deleteRow(rowIndex);
}
```

Comment: Esa es mi duda..que no se como pasarle la fila que quiero eliminar..y con tu codigo se eliminara siempre la primera no? @dddenis.